# Criteria for a poset complex to be contractible

Tags: posets, simplicial-complexes

I would like to know if there are nice criteria to know if the ordered complex $C$ induced by a poset is contractible. I am also interested in the same question for subcomplexes of $C$.

$C$ happens to be a flag complex, and I found that all induced subcomplexes are contractible iff the underlying graph of $C$ is chordal.

However, this doesn't fit my purposes.

Do you know any result in this respect?

Comment: Glib answer: it's contractible if the poset has a minimal or maximal element :)

Comment: There are lots of results that are useful, like Quillen's theorem A.  Bjorner's handbook chapter on poset topology is also quite useful.  Note that for a flag complex, chordal is equivalent to all INDUCED subcomplexes being contractible, not arbitrary ones.

Comment: Actually, a simplicial complex must be a flag complex for all induced subcomplexes to be contractible.  Otherwise, you have a clique in the 1-skeleton which is not the boundary of a simplex and that induced subgraph is not contractible.

Comment: whoops, above I of course mean "minimum or maximum" (or "unique minimal or unique maximal element")

Comment: Baclawski and Bjorner, "Fixed Points in Partially Ordered Sets," Advances in Mathematics 31 (1979) contains related results on page 271.